# shiny dashboard highchart react to two inputs, not working

Tags: r, plot, shiny, leaflet, reactive

I recently added a highchart to my shiny dashboard that reacts to clicking in specific polygons inside a leaflet map.

Depending on the polygon clicked, the data for the highchart is either taken from 1 dataframe, or a combination of 2 dataframes.

This works. However, I also have a 'map reset' button which resets the polygons clicked on the map. I am trying to code it so this reset button also resets the highchart.

However, all options I tried so far result in a blank highchart from the start, which doesn't change.

```
df1<- data.frame(location = c(3,4), "2013" = c(900, 100), "2014" = c(700, 600))
df2<- data.frame(location = c(1,2), "2013" = c(1400, 1500),
"2014" = c(1600, 1700), , location1 = c(3,4)))



click_shape <- eventReactive(input$map_shape_click, {

c <- input$map_shape_click$id
return(c)
})


data_for_chart <- reactive({

# if top level polygon, return data from that level
if(is.null(click_shape())) {return(df1[FALSE,])
}else if(click_shape() %in% df1){

c<- tolower(click_shape())
return(df1[df$location  == c,] %>% gather(key = "year", value = GHA_N, 2:3))

# if second level, return data from top + second level  
}else if(click_shape() %in% df2){
  c<- tolower(click_shape())
  d<- tolower(df2$location[df2$location == click_shape()])
  return(df1[df1$location == d,] %>% 
           rbind(df2[df2$location == c,]) %>% gather(key = "year", value = GHA_N, 2:3))

# if no appropriate data is found, don't plot 
}else{
  return(df1[FALSE,])
}
```

})

I tried adding the reset button to the eventreactive like so:

```
click_shape <- eventReactive(c(input$map_shape_click,input$reset) {

   if(input$map_shape_click) {
 c <- input$map_shape_click$id
   return(c)
}else{
   return(NULL)
})
```

thinking the data_for_chart function would react to this by not plotting the data. However, it keeps the highchart blank from the moment you start the shiny app!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question:

by first adding a reactive value which contains the click_shape event

```
value<- reactiveValues(click_shape = NULL)
```

and then adding a second observe event that modifies the click_shape

```
observeEvent(input$reset, { 
value$click_shape <- NULL
})
```

next to the original observeEvent

```
observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {

value$click_shape <- input$map_shape_click$id
})
```

this way, two observe events can modify the click_shape event.